# Where was the picnic/fishing scene in the movie "Three Billboards..." filmed?

Tags: film-location, three-billboards-outside-ebbing

I recently watched the movie Three Billboards Outside Ebbing, Missouri and what a fantastic movie. There's a scene in the movie where Woody Harrelson, his wife, and kids go out for a picnic and camp on the bank of a river or lake. The location is just breathtaking for me. Now I know Ebbing is actually Sylva, NC, but their [tourism website](https://www.romanticasheville.com/sylva.htm) does NOT mention this location, they mention everything else, so I'm assuming it is someplace else. I would love to go visit that location, does anyone know where it is?

Here's an image for reference:
[image]

Comment: Probably somewhere on this list - http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5027774/locations?ref_=ttrel_sa_4

Comment: https://www.exploreasheville.com/things-to-do/recreation-nature/

Comment: I think this area is around Lake Glenville.